# Changing the same column type in all tables in PostgreSQL. The column contains the data

Tags: postgresql

The schema name is postgre_x_schema and the column name is y_column.
Column type is numeric, data available(1 and 0 ).
I will convert the column and set to boolean (1 = 'TRUE' and 0='FALSE) '.
But how can I do this on all tables.

*300 tables have the same column and in data.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a column of a table, you use the ALTER TABLE statement with RENAME COLUMN clause as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_column_name;
```

In this statement:

1. First, specify the name of the table that contains the column which you want to rename after the `ALTER TABLE` clause.
2. Second, provide name of the column that you want to rename after the `RENAME COLUMN` keywords.
3. Third, specify the new name for the column after the `TO` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I will not change the name of the table. I will convert the type of the table. I want convert  integer to  boolean. But 300 tables have the same column. It also contains data. how can do this?

Comment: If you read my answer twice it could help you to solve the problem :)